# How to obtain client certificate used to authenticate in my Rust Tonic service?

Tags: rust, grpc, mtls, rust-tonic

In my Rust Tonic setup, I have configured mTLS (mutual TLS) authentication between client and server.

Now, I would like to use the data stored in client certificate
a) for authorizing access (interceptor)
b) use in providing the service (ie. I want to see `Hello Petr` if Petr is connecting)

I could not find any examples about this, and traversing Tonic source code didn't help me, too.

Answer (score 2):

After asking on discord channel [tokio/tonic](https://discord.com/channels/500028886025895936/628706823104626710/855104879198076928), I got the solution (thanks Lucio Franco!) and also found that there actually *is* an example in tonic (yes my research was not good enough).

For anyone interested, this is the example code:
https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/tls_client_auth/server.rs

Brief summary:

the `request` parameter, provided in each method generated for the service, contains parameter [peer_certs()](https://discord.com/channels/500028886025895936/628706823104626710/855105099457363989) which returns all the user certificates.

These can be then iterated, and their bytes parsed. I used crate [x509-parser](https://crates.io/crates/x509-parser) which works great for me, but others might be probably used as well.