# How do I pass details of a client certificate to a hyper HTTPS router?

Tags: rust, hyper

I found [this example](https://github.com/rustls/hyper-rustls/blob/56c60ed3f5497caebb3335a4bb9b69cf9f2f69c0/examples/server.rs), but it is not clear how to pass details of the client certificate to the router, such as the subject.
I would like to implement some logic that depends on details of the certificate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033356/175554 may help